# How do I order a fetchXml result set with linked entities first by a value of the linked entity, then by a value of the linking entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I am trying to formulate a *fetchXml* query that returns a set of entities in the same order as would the following SQL statement:

```
select
   t1.col_1
   t2.col_2
from
   tab_one  t1                   join
   tab_two  t2 on t1.id = t2.id
order by
   t2.col_2,
   t1.col_1
```

With the following approach, the result set is ordered by `t1.col_1`.

```
<fetch mapping="logical" version="1.0">

  <entity name="tab_one">
    <attribute name="col_1" />

    <link-entity name="tab_two" from="id" to="id" alias="t2" link-type="inner">

      <attribute name="col_2" />
      <order attribute="col_2" />
    </link-entity>

    <order attribute="col_1" />

  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Where or in what order to I have to put the `<order attribute ...>` tags so that the result set is returned first order by `t2.col_2` then `t1.col_1`?

Comment: according to [blog](https://markcarrington.dev/2019/12/10/inside-fetchxml-pt-4-order/), fetch will bydefault order by tab_one attribute and then tab_two. I tried in one of my  fethcxml and got the same results

Comment: This is, unfortunately, what I had to learn the hard way, too.